# Apparently I'm corrupting the stack - but how?

Tags: c, matlab, segmentation-fault

I have a very simple program, listed below, which reads a value from a `.mat` file (a data file from Matlab) and prints it. For some reason, I get a segfault error *after exiting main()* - I can run `gdb my_program` and step through the entire method, but as soon as `main()` finishes, I enter some method in a Matlab related library (`libmwfl.so`, a dependency of `libmat.so`) which throws a segfault.

I am completely new to C programming, but some reading up I suspect that I'm either somehow [corrupting the stack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4807923/38055) or [calling some destructor twice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5059855/38055). However, I can't see any of those in my code - and as I said, I can step through my code with the debugger without problems.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mat.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    double value;
    MATFile *datafile;
    datafile = matOpen("test.mat", "r");

    mxArray *mxv;
    mxv = matGetVariable(datafile, "value");
    value = *mxGetPr(mxv);
    mxFree(mxv);
    matClose(datafile);

    printf("The value fetched from the .mat file was: %f", value);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If I were in your shoes, I would check if datafile is NULL (which would mean the file could not be opened).

Comment: @GeorgeStamatiou Looking at the program, for a moment, even I felt the same. But if that were the case program would have ( in all probability) crashed within `main` due to a NULL pointer dereference and not after exiting `main` as the OP indicates. The answer by Giuseppe Guerrini spotted the exact problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The documentation recommends to use the function `mxDestroyArray` instead of `mxFree` to free an `mxArray`. By using `mxFree` you probably mess up the matlab's heap. From the [documentation](http://matlab.izmiran.ru/help/techdoc/matlab_external/ch3_me23.html)

> **Improperly Destroying an mxArray**
>
> You cannot use **`mxFree`** to destroy an **`mxArray`**.
>
> **Warning**:   You are attempting to call **`mxFree`** on a **`<class-id>`** array.  The destructor for **`mxArrays`** is **`mxDestroyArray`**; please call
>   this  instead. MATLAB will attempt to fix the problem and continue,
>   but  this will result in memory faults in future releases.
>
> **Example That Causes Warning**
>
> In the following example, **`mxFree`** does not destroy the array object.
>   This operation frees the structure header associated with the array,
>   but MATLAB will still operate as if the array object needs to be
>   destroyed. Thus MATLAB will try to destroy the array object, and in
>   the process, attempt to free its structure header again.
>
> **`mxArray *temp = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,1,mxREAL);`**
>
> ```
>   ...
> ```
>
> **`mxFree(temp);  /* INCORRECT */`**
>
> **Solution.**
>
> Call **`mxDestroyArray`** instead.
>
> **`mxDestroyArray(temp);  /* CORRECT */`**

Comment: This works perfectly - thanks a lot! However, I haven't seen that part of the documentation. Would you care to provide a link? (There might be more things there I could use to know... ;) )

Comment: @TomasLycken Here you go. [Documentation](http://matlab.izmiran.ru/help/techdoc/matlab_external/ch3_me23.html)